# Quandl API Stock Data Points

Tags: python-2.7, quandl

I am trying to get stock data using quandl (in python 2.7), and I am wondering if its possible to get the price of a share at different times of a single day? So for instance could I get the price of a stock at 9:30, then 10:00, then 10:30, etc using quandl? If so, please leave a comment to a link or just tell me the method I can use. I have been unable to find something like this, so any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this was released [last year.](https://blog.quandl.com/quandl-launches-intraday-data-2)

The datasources available are [here](https://www.quandl.com/publishers/as), have you purchased access to intra-day pricing? It's about $250 a year.

Here is an example of how to pull intra-day for a day through API:

```
https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/databases/ASINDU/download?download_type=20160104
```

Comment: I have not purchased that, and this is for a school (high school) project, so I would rather not have to buy anything. Is there maybe a free version, or an entirely different API that would allow me to get hour by hour data?

Comment: It's tougher if you're doing it free, if you're paying there is a scale from daily to secondly, but understand it's for school. Try this https://www.quantshare.com/sa-426-6-ways-to-download-free-intraday-and-tick-data-for-the-us-stock-market

Comment: ok the google finance looks promising! However, I am not familiar with this formatting using links. I am used to importing, then calling specific functions or methods. How do you use these links in python code? I tried having like data=https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=[30]&p=[1]d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q=[AAPL], then printing data but that doesn't work. How do you use these?

Comment: ok so using this:print json.dumps(getQuotes('AAPL'), indent=2) could I add a date/time as a parameter?